# Git gui show code compare selected file

Tags: git, git-gui, codecompare

I'm trying show the code compare with the git gui.

I configured tool->add with `git diff -y` but when I execute shows every file and I want to see just the file selected.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this,

click tools-> add

and write: `git difftool -y $FILENAME`

and enable the option Run only if a diff is selected($FILENAME not empty)